# How to define withTrased on model ? (Laravel 5.3)

Tags: mongodb, laravel, laravel-5.3, soft-delete, eloquent

My model is like this :

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent; 
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\HybridRelations;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
class Message extends Eloquent
{
    use HybridRelations;  
    use SoftDeletes; 
    protected $connection = 'mongodb';
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
    protected $fillable = ['subject', 'information', 'created_at', 'update_at'];
}
```

If I get data from model like this :

```
Message::withTrashed()->find($id);
```

I success get data with trashed

But I want define it on the model

So when I call :

```
Message::find($id);
```

It also get data with trashed

How can I do it?

Comment: try deleting `use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;` and `use SoftDeletes;` from your model. It should disable soft delete features

Comment: @Autista_z, I want set withTrashed on the model without delete it. Whether it can be done?

Comment: Well, then i thing just define your own method e.g. `Message::findW($id);` Find method will be protected

Comment: @Autista_z, True what you say. Seems it can not be done